# Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in SQL to search for an example from a table in a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Using the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` in SQL can obtain the following:

```
TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
mytab0, mytab0_col0
mytab0, mytab0_col1
.
.
.
mytab1, mytab1_col0
mytab1, mytab1_col1
.
.
.
```

`SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

I have tried various ways, functions and CTEs to generate a new column, say, "example" that will use the values from `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME` to conduct what is equivalent to a select statement that will yield the result of, for example:

`SELECT TOP(1) mytab0_col0 WHERE mytab0_col0 IS NOT NULL FROM mytab0`

This output would then need to go into an example column.

I have tried to use a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.foo(@input_table VARCHAR(250), @input_columns VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)


AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value VARCHAR(250)
    DECLARE @tab_name VARCHAR(250)

    SET @tab_name = @input_table
    
    SELECT @return_value = @input_columns
    FROM @tab_name
    WHERE @input_columns IS NOT NULL

   
    RETURN @return_value

END;
```

This fails because the `FROM @tab_name` expects an actual table and not a varchar. Doing this just won't work for many reasons, although this does:

```
declare @xvar as VARCHAR(250)
select @xvar = [mytab0_col0]
from mytab0
where [mytab0_col0] is not null
print @xvar
```

I have also tried to create a CTE and then INSERT INTO or use a function with a CTE which was unsuccessful.

Comment: Have you tried something like `SELECT 'select ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + ... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Comment: you need to investigate _dynamic sql queries_. Construct the query in an `nvarchar` variable then you can execute it with `sp_executesql`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-sql/ butyou can't do this from a function.

Comment: @jarlh So this outputs the equivalent of the right select statement (`SELECT 'select top(1) ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`), the next step would be to use these values to actually run a query to update a column. Any advice on how to proceed from here?

EDIT: Potentially the next step is what @ChrisSchaller mentioned?

Comment: So are you just after a procedure that will `SELECT` an arbitrary row/column from your table where the value of the column isn't `NULL`? You *can't* do what you are after in a `FUNCTION` as you *cannot* use dynamic SQL in a function.

Comment: @Larnu In essence, I need to use the values from `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME` to generate a column that is the output of every value in `TABLE_NAME` combined with every possible `COLUMN_NAME`, where it is not null. This effectively is the same as the statement `SELECT 'select top(1) ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` executed row by row.

Comment: So you want a single column of every non-`NULL` value in your database? That's a terrible idea; different data types don't mix well in a single column. Smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) to me; what is the problem you are *actually* trying to solve here?

Comment: That's not the case. I am creating a table which has the following items, forgive the csv format:

table_name, column_name, type, example as headers. An example row is: table1,column0,varchar,hello. A second row would be, for example, table1,column1,varchar,baz. I hope this clarifies, @Larnu, feel free to run information.schema.columns yourself. I will parse all the different types as strings since I do not need examples of Dates, for instance.

Comment: I'm aware of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects, @clownshoez, though I don't use them intentionally as the `sys` objects are much better choices as they include *all* the relevant information for the objects in SQL Server.... As for the problem, this still smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. What do you want to occur when you have `datetime2`, `int`, `varbinary`, and `varchar` columns in that one table? You *can't* implicitly (or explicitly) convert an `int` to a `datetime2`, so what happens then? An error?

Comment: Sorry for dragging this on. Simply put, I do not need to concern myself with coercing types. I only need an example that is not null from that table at that specific column in line with the rest of the row. If it is not a string or cannot be cast as a string it can be left null. @Larnu, thanks for your patience. I'm not in a position to debate the validity of the goal here, it's the task I was given. Make a table, manually or otherwise, of all the columns in our DB with an example.

Comment: *"I do not need to concern myself with coercing types"* But you *have* to. You *can't* have 2 different data types in  the same column, a column *must* be defined as a single data type. If you have multiple data types involved then [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will be used, and that very likely will end up with an error.

Comment: @Larnu Can I not just CAST() as varchar and expect NULL if it fails?

Comment: You could, but you could easily get some nonsense data and data loss.

Comment: Happy to take that risk. The manual option is not something I'm willing to do, we have hundreds of tables and thousands of columns, @Larnu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, this is a mess, but it works. Though I could try to explain, it's more important you understand how this works yourself, and you *need* to take the time to do so. Dynamic SQL is not an easy tool to use and in the wrong hands, dangerous. I've made this as safe as possible from injection attacks, so if you are going to change it, ensure that you don't open avenues.

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname,
        @TableName sysname;

SET @SchemaName = N'dbo';
SET @TableName = N'YourTable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @SelectDelimiter nvarchar(20) = N',' + @CRLF + N'             ',
        @ValuesDelimiter nvarchar(50) = N',' + @CRLF + N'                         ';

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
              N'       t.[name] AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
              N'       V.ColumnName,' + @CRLF +
              N'       ct.[name] AS DataType,' + @CRLF +
              N'       V.MaxColumnValue' + @CRLF +
              N'FROM (SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'MAX(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N') AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name])),@SelectDelimiter) + @CRLF +
              N'      FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N') YT' + @CRLF + 
              N'      CROSS APPLY (VALUES' + STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'(N' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],'''') + N', CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),YT.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N'))'),@ValuesDelimiter) + N')V(ColumnName,MaxColumnValue)' + @CRLF +
              N'      JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.[name] = @SchemaName' + @CRLF +
              N'      JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id' + @CRLF +
              N'      JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id' + @CRLF +
              N'                        AND c.[name] = V.ColumnName' + @CRLF + 
              N'      JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id' + @CRLF +
              N'WHERE t.[name] = @TableName;'
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE s.[name] = @SchemaName
  AND t.[name] = @TableName
GROUP BY s.[name],
         t.[name];

--SELECT @SQL; --Your debugging friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SchemaName sysname, @TableName sysname', @SchemaName, @TableName;
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience & understanding. I will take the time to read through and implement this script.